# Inconsistencies with which command

Tags: linux, bash, path, node.js, which

I'm using the [n](https://github.com/tj/n) tool to update my current version of node, but something strange is happening.

I ran `sudo n latest` which in theory fetches the latest version of Node (`v0.12.0` and installs it somewhere that's already on my `$PATH`.

However, running `node -v` shows `v0.10.25`. I figured that there was another version of the node exe somewhere else on my path.

`which node` shows `/usr/local/bin/node`.

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/node
$ node -v
v0.10.25
$ ./node -v
v0.12.0
```

It's there and installed and `/usr/local/bin` is on my `$PATH`.

In what case would `which` point to the wrong binary?

I've restarted bash and made sure that there are no dud node binaries in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. Also made sure that it wasn't a symlink.

```
$ ls -lah | grep node
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  20M Feb 14 14:56 node
```

And that it definitely was a binary.

```
$ file node
node: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look for complicated solutions and you miss the glaringly obvious.

I switched into `zsh` to see whether the issue was with bash. The node version was correct.

I had `alias node=nodejs` in `~/.bash_aliases`...

Obivously `which` doesn't take that into account. I think there was some issue with the apt-get package for Node with Ubuntu, which created `nodejs` binaries rather than `node`. Obviously I'd aliased it rather than symlinking.

Lesson learned.